# hover property not working properly

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrect but hover is not working as I want. As you seen, when putting cursor on any menu its background looks like weird. 
I'm not trying to copy anything but my intention is to do the same as on http://www.nfl.com/ 
As soon as you put your cursor on any menu, a full background blue color is activated and color name alter to white.
To finish off, there are those vertical bars after each menu. I have no idea how to do that

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYDn5.png

.nav {
width: 1000px;
height: 35px;
background: #2F2929; 
position: relative;
top: -13px;
}

.nav ul {
list-style: none;
padding-left: 0;
text-align: center;
word-spacing: 20px;
}

.nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
padding-top: 9px;
}

.nav ul li:hover {
background: #585454;
}

.nav ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: "Georgia", serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: `background` should be `background-color` first off

Comment: the full markup would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your `li` is not the height of its parent. You can fix by applying a padding to the whole element (not only `padding-top`).

Made you a [mock in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nemoxu/edit?html,css,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background: #2F2929; 
    position: relative;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 8px;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

.nav ul li:hover {
    background: #585454;
}

.nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Georgia", serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: You are right, my friend. Would you mind explaining this part: "Your li is not the height of its parent."? I don't understand. Sorry. You code was pretty good, but there are a space between hover and left side of News (and right side of Store). Is there any way to fix it? JesseEarley created a code as well, and there were those white traces in vertical among menus, how to do that in your code? thanks in advance

Comment: Look at this: 
<http://i1356.photobucket.com/albums/q724/tiago1801/Screenshot_10_zpssy2svcj5.png>
Menus are not align centered. Those verical traces are not full as your after alteration and to finish off there is some space after "Store". Is there any way to fix it? thanks in advance

Comment: Well, in `nav>ul>li>a` `li` is the parent container of `a` and `ul` is the parent container of `li`. You should check 'the css box model' to really understand the concept.
For the fix, you need to understand which element you are styling and it's difficult to catch it from a screenshot. Try using some real code instead.
It's not the best solution, but [here's what can be done](http://jsbin.com/nemoxu/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: when tracing those vertical lines, there are some gaps among menus. Maybe, I'm using word-spacing in wrong way, not sure.

Comment: In the example i removed `word-spacing` as it's used to separate words within a group of words (ex. a `p` tag).  
Try the jsbin example on my last comment (or in the answer, it's updated)

Comment: I did that later as well. It did not work using border-right and left with 1px solid white. there are two traces centering menus

Comment: I updated the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nemoxu/edit?html,css,output) with `li {float:left; border-right: 1px solid #fff;}`   
This will position each `li` next to each other.  
There are at least 5 different ways (i can think of) for achieving what you want.  
I would like to help you further but not seeing your code makes it a guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

```css
.nav {
width: 1000px;
height: 35px;
background: #2F2929; 
position: relative;
top: -13px;
}

.nav ul {
list-style: none;
padding-left: 0;
text-align: center;
word-spacing: 20px;
}

.nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
padding-top: 9px;
}


.nav ul li a {
display:inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: "Georgia", serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
background: #585454;
color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
   <ul>
      <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: [URL=http://s1356.photobucket.com/user/tiago1801/media/Screenshot_9_zpsn8oik0ut.png.html]

Your code didn't work properly when I typed. Did I do wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're trying to do? (If I understood your problem correctly)

https://jsfiddle.net/97j5k037/1/

```
  .nav {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 35px;
        background: #2F2929;
        position: relative;
        top: -13px;
    }
    .nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 0;
        text-align: center;
        word-spacing: 20px;
    }
    .nav ul li {
        border-right: 1px solid white;
        float: left;
    }
    .nav ul li ul {
        display: none;
    }
    .nav ul li:hover {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .nav ul li:hover ul {
        background-color: red;
        display: block;
    }
    .nav ul li ul li {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
    .nav ul li a,
    .nav ul li:hover a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 9px;
        display: block;
    }

<nav class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Explanation:
The following code shows how to setup the parent level list item, and the nested unordered list and list items (these will become the children drop-down menu). This snippet just shows one of the parent list items.

```
<li>
   <a href="#">Link 1</a>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

This CSS will hide the child menu, since you don't want it to display by default

```
.nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
```

Since you want the child unordered list to show on the hover of the parent list item, you need the following CSS (I added the red background just to distinguish from the parent, it can be any color you want)

```
.nav ul li:hover ul {
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
}
```

Since you wanted a line separating the parent list items, I added a border-right to them

```
.nav ul li {
            border-right: 1px solid white;
            float: left;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I was trying to do. At the same time, the other part of code got crazy lol

Comment: Would you mind explaining all those selectors, please?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I used Visual Studio to format the code, and well, I'm not sure what happened with the HTML when I copied/pasted it. Editing my answer right now to include an explanation.

Comment: This is how my code for that div is right now: 
<http://i1356.photobucket.com/albums/q724/tiago1801/Screenshot_11_zpstzfueyn5.png>
If I try to make those vertical traces using border-right will be quite a bit weird because there will some space inside box and both extremes of side as well.
Probably, I did something bad. Not sure.

Comment: I can't say for sure without seeing your markup and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Could give this a try.

```
.nav ul.has-sub:hover > li,
.nav ul li.has-sub:hover > div {
    background: #newcolor;
    border-color: #newcolor;
}

.nav ul li.has-sub:hover > ul,
.nav ul li.has-sub:hover > div {
    display: block;
}

.nav > ul > li.has-sub > a:hover,
.nav > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a {
    background: #newcolor;
    border-color: #newcolor;
}
```